# not utf-8 HTML Encoding for French characters

Tags: utf-8

To use the utf-8 tag I must save the html in unicode. I need a working tag that can save the html file in plain text and show the French characters. Just like ISO-8859-1 for German.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 are just different byte encodings of the same character set (Unicode).  If you want to use UTF-8 encoded byte octets in your HTML, you have to save the HTML in UTF-8 encoding.  Just like if you want to use ISO-8859-1 encoded byte octets, you have to save the HTML in ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Otherwise, use HTML entities in `&<name>;` or `&#<codepoint>;` format for non-ASCII Unicode characters, instead of raw byte octets.  Many Unicode codepoints have reserved entity names (see the [W3C Character Entity Reference Chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)), otherwise you can use the actual Unicode numeric codepoint value instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really not that good in understanding how computers work. It is just I make simple htmls in notepad. I use the meta charset tags windows-1251 for cyrilic and ISO-8859-1 for german. It works perfect. I though other languages will be that easy too. I drop it. Thanks again

Comment: A `<meta>` charset tag must match the actual file encoding. If you specify UTF-8 in the `<meta>`, tell Notepad to save the file as UTF-8. The Save dialog has an *Encoding* drop-down list that allows you to pick *ANSI* (the default), *UTF-8*, or *UTF-16*. *ANSI* uses the current language of the local machine (so, for non-ASCII characters, Windows-1251 would only work on a machine using a Cyrillic-based language, and ISO-8859-1 would only work on a machine using a Latin1-based language). The majority of the world uses UTF-8 for just about everything nowadays, so you should stick with that.